# Loop infinito, orientação a objetos

Tags: php, pdo, loop

Bom, andei dando uma pesquisada, achei vários tópicos falando sobre o assunto, mas nenhum deles me foram util, então resolvi recorrer ao *Stack Overflow*.

Tenho uma função para listar todos os tickets do usuário que esteja com a sessão aberta:

```
public function list_ticket() {
        try {
            $session = $_SESSION[SESSION_PREFIX . 'email_username'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE email=:session ORDER BY id DESC";
            $pdo = $this->connection()->prepare($sql);
            $pdo->bindParam(':session', $session, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo->execute();
            return $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Ocorreu um erro: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' Na linha: ' . $e->getLine() . ' No arquivo: ' . $e->getFile());
        }
    }
```

Até aí beleza, vamos ao principal, tenho no meu html, um `while` onde coloco todo o meu bloco de códigos `HTML`, porém quando uso o `while`, ele captura apenas 1 dado da minha tabela e entra em `Loop Infinito`, veja abaixo a estrutura:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket #</th>
            <th>Criado em</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Assunto</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = $ticket->list_ticket()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[3]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[4]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[5]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    switch ($row[7]) {
                        case 0:
                            echo '<span class="label label-success">Aberto</span>';
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            echo '<span class="label label-info">Respondido</span>';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            echo '<span class="label label-danger">Fechado</span>';
                            break;
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aguardo respostas.

Comment: Eu já tentei, me retorna o seguinte erro: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O loop infinito acontece porque a cada volta do while o mesmo resultado é retornado o *resultset* não avança ou seja a primeira linha da tabela é retornada `N` vezes e nunca retornará false aí o while não para mesmo.

Uma opção é jogar o while para dentro da função e retornar um array completo.

Função

```
$pdo->execute();
$lista = array();
while($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
   $lista[] = $row;
}
return $lista;
```

Na chamada do seu código faça:

```
foreach($ticket->list_ticket() as $row){ ...
```

Ou

```
$arr = $ticket->list_ticket()
foreach($arr as $row){ ...
```

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, porém agora nem carrega mais a página... não estou conseguindo proceder com o projeto...

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves, coloque isso no começo do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Coloquei, não está mostrando erro algum, o loop continua depois de algum tempo parado.

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves edite a resposta, faltou o `return $lista`

Comment: Haha, falta de atenção de minha parte também, obrigado, problema solucionado.